# Change image path when right click "save image as"

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, contextmenu

Is it possible to have an image without watermark on my page and when people try to download the image by accessing the right click menu and "save image as". To let them download an image with the watermark applied to it?

Comment: It may be possible you could support this with a HTML5 canvas... as you can set different source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you can check which mouse button was pressed in a `mousedown` event handler and if it was the right button change the source of the image:

```
​$('img').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', '_watermark.jpg');
    }
});​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s6A9m/

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible, as you haven't any information about what is user currently doing with these images. You can, however, apply your watermark to the bottom or to the top of the image and then just hide part of an image in your html

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you're going to have to break the normal UX (User eXperience) to do this.

- You could disable the right-click context menu and then create your own (say just for the images you want to watermark) so that when a user right-clicks an image, they are given the option to download the image but they are directed to the watermarked element instead of the non-watermarked element.

Here is the first search result from the search: "jQuery context menu"

> http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/

- You could also remove the users ability to right-click the image by placing a transparent element over the image that does not allow the `click` event to reach the image. Then give the user a clearly labeled link to download the image (but of-course you just direct the user to the watermarked image).

Here is a demo of this method: http://jsfiddle.net/xAjDp/

HTML --

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="[src]" />
</div>
<a href="[src]">Download Image</a>​
```

CSS --

```
.container {
    position : relative;
    display  : inline-block;

    /*IE7&6 Compatibility*/
    *display : inline;
    zoom     : 1;
    _height  : 366px;
}
.container .overlay {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    opacity    : 0;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=0);
    zoom       : 1;/*give the element "hasLayout"*/
}​
```

Comment: I think a combination of the 2 would work out great, to have an extra security when people turn off javascript...

Comment: @user1260349 You have to realize that any determined user will be able to "steal" your non-watermarked images. If you output them to the browser, it's out of your control and anybody that knows HTML can just look at the source of the page to find the URL of the image.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that fact, but the more people I can exclude from stealing the better... ofc there's always screenshots :s But I'm not really worried about that cause they'll only be able to screenshot the thumbnail that way.
I would also try to not set the path of the img directly in my html but let it grab it dynamically with php.

Comment: @joopmicroop If you are setting the path via PHP then it's being outputted to the browser (and is visible in the source), unless you are using an AJAX request to grab the file-names/images and adding them to the DOM that way (which an advanced user could still inspect the DOM to find urls). Perhaps you can set a JS array/object to store all of the sources, then on page-load you can change the source of all of the images, that way they aren't hard-coded into the HTML. If you do this, make sure to give the images a valid hard-coded source so the browser doesn't try to load useless assets.