# Watermark an image upon download...is it possible?

Tags: php, jquery, gd, watermark

Simple question with yes/no answer and if yes...then how?

Suppose you have an HTML page with an image on it without any sort of watermark.

**Is it possible to place a watermark on that image if a user saves it to their computer?**

I need a simple function that watermarks an image upon download or save...

**I do understand that once the image loads in the browser, it is technically downloaded, so is there a way to display the image without a watermark on screen, and if the user opens browser cache, he/she finds a watermarked copy?**

If anybody has done this using any platform (PHP, GD, jQuery, etc.), your contribution would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot tell the difference between someone downloading an image for viewing inside a web page (e.g. `<img src="...">`) or someone directly accessing an image to view/download it outside of an image. You'd have to watermark ALL of your images, regardless of how the user will be displaying them.

Comment: not watermark on screen .. screen is browser ..is it?what  if he save the page !!

Comment: i think you are putting an ugly watermark thats why you dont to show it in the beginning :-)

Comment: Whatever the user sees is what is in the cache.  That is the whole point of a cache.  You could make it uncachable and have a link to a watermarked version, but that still doesn't prevent the user from simply retrieving the file the way the browser does (as @Marc B mentions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change image path when right click "save image as"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642345/change-image-path-when-right-click-save-image-as)

Comment: Also, what prevents the person from taking a screen cap?  This is the crux of DRM, watermarking, etc.  If the user wants it, they will find a way to get it.  If you really want a watermark, don't give the user any avenue to get/see the image without a watermark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can read how to do it with PHP: http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/

I personally don't think that it is possible with javascript, because as you already have said yourself, it is already downloaded.
But don't nail me on that.

On the server side it is for sure possible, as you can see in the above link.

Comment: +1 to this.  See also [GD and Image Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) as well as [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score 3):

One trick might be to combine 2 images, so they become one.
I have image A:
[image]

Then I add image B (watermark version)
[image]

So when you display the image for the user you use one as background and the other one as image, so when user tries to download, they will get only one part. Of course as already mentioned, the user will be able to get all they can see on the screen, but most users won't be able to combine the images properly.

Please note that the image on top must be transparent.

I would recommend doing this server side and cache the modified images when you have cut out the watermark

Comment: or i right-click your image and choose view background image. That is not really a proper way

Comment: As I said in my first answer "...the user wil able to get all they can see on the screen...", but this will create a solution that makes it hard for users to grab your images without having to do a lot of work.

Comment: I agree with Bjørne's solution because if the user is going out of his/her way, they are aware of the copyright infringement, which by the way is placed in the terms of use section of any standard website. Apart from this one can use cryptography to inject the copyright info in the images, also disable right-clicks and whatnot to make it obvious that the information/images displayed is just for viewing purposes and not "borrowing".

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternate solution is to contain the image inside an element with a hidden overflow.
For example:

Your image has a height of `200px`, you add an extra `20px` watermark (when uploading) at the bottom of the image (so it isn't actually on top of the image). So the total image now has a height of `220px;` but you place it inside an element give that element a `200px` height and a hidden overflow.

Comment: does that really make sense when the watermark is under the picture. then i open it in paint and cut the bottom off

Comment: great suggestion, that is exactly what I found out from my research, imagine getting a full screen image, watermarking it in the center, and then having another div on top with just the segment/slice that is not watermarked...and one could go further by slicing up the image and then putting it back together, which is fairly simple via php...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the source of the image when a user right-clicks it. This way you can change the source to the watermarked version when the user tries to save the image.

Yes, the user will already have the non-watermarked version in their cache, but only advanced users are going to know how to get to those images.

```
$('img').on('mousedown', function (event) {

    //check which mouse button was clicked, 1 == left, 2 == middle, 3 == right
    if (event.which == 3) {

        //update the source of this image
        this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', '_watermarked.jpg');
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/s6A9m/

Comment: don't works at all. Have you tried to right click and then choose view image? Normally you get the new image to see, but sometimes it happens that the context menu is fast enough and you see the old image

Comment: @SvenBieder `don't works at all.` -- I've tested this in IE7-8, Chrome 17, Firefox 10, Safari 5. Most likely you're internet connection isn't lightning last so you just need to pre-load the watermarked image so it changes quickly. In each browser I tested when I saved the image, it saved the watermark version.

Comment: I haven't tried to directly save the image. I have done it like I normally do it myself. At first view the image before saving. But you are right I'm at work and the connection sucks. But that means you must be aware that user that have not at that moment full broadband might see the watermark picture, or might see the original one. And I also guess he wants a automatic watermarking function, that he don't needs to upload 2 images for every image he wants to display. But I like the approach.

Comment: either way, you can just disable right click and print screen via jquery...my main thing is to see if we together can think of some way to protect intellectual and creative property while showing our work... thank you for these suggestions Jasper!

Comment: Also does not prevent them from simply dragging the image to their desktop

Answer (score 1):

Anything that the user can see they can take. There is no way to watermark ONLY if downloaded. When an image is displayed in the browser it has already downloaded.

There are several approaches you could take. I would recommend you use PHP to add the watermark to the image before it is displayed. This means that all protected images on the site will display a visible watermark. A second approach I have seen used is to display a low quality version that is not watermarked, but restrict the full quality version to only those who are supposed to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. All you have to do is,

Call the download function, in which we can implement the downloading of watermarked images.
I have used AngularJS, HTML, JQuery and watermarkJS which you find here(http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/)

HTML:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="DownloadSample()">Download Sample</a>`

Javascript:

```
$scope.selectedWatermarkType = 'Text';
$scope.selectedPosition = 'Bottom-left';
$scope.text = 'Sample Watermark';
$scope.size = '45';
$scope.selectedFont = 'Arial';
$scope.ColorCodeGlobalObj.colorcode = 'ffff';

$scope.DownloadSample = function () {
if ($scope.selectedWatermarkType == 'Text') {
                if ($scope.selectedPosition == 'Bottom-left') {
                    watermark(['/assets/js/node_modules/watermarkjs/examples/img/shepherd.jpg'])
                    .image(watermark.text.lowerRight($scope.text, $scope.size + 'px ' + $scope.selectedFont, '#' + $scope.ColorCodeGlobalObj.colorcode, 0.5))
                    .then(function (img) {
                        saveImageAs(img);
                    });
                }
}
```

'img' is the watermarked image object which can be used to download the image.

```
function saveImageAs(imgOrURL) {
        imgOrURL.src.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
        if (typeof imgOrURL == 'object')
            imgOrURL = imgOrURL.src;

        var link = document.createElement("a");

        link.setAttribute("href", imgOrURL);
        link.setAttribute("download", 'watermarkSample.png');
        link.click();
    }
```

This code performs download of watermarked image. Still the unwatermarked image is available in the mentioned srcpath which can be appended to an 'img' tag and can be viewed.

Hope this helps !